# Is there a python strip function equivalent in javascript?

Tags: javascript, python

Python's strip function is used to remove given characters from the beginning and end of the string. How to create a similar function in javascript?

Example:

```
str = "'^$   *# smart kitty &  ''^$*   '^";
newStr = str.strip(" '^$*#&");
console.log(newStr);
```

Output:

```
smart kitty
```

Comment: I know, I can use something like `str.replace(/(^\s*&)|(&\s*$)/g, '')` to remove preceding and trailing instance of `&`. But what will be the regex in case of several characters?

Comment: As a side note, your Python code really shouldn't be calling the variable `str`, as that hides the name of the type/function of the same name.

Comment: Do you know about [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) in regexp? The way to find any instance of any of `$`, `*`, `#`, or `&`, instead of just any instance of `&`, is to use the character class `[$*#&]`.

Comment: @abarnert I wrote a javascript code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple but not very effective way would be to look for the characters and remove them:

```
function strip(str, remove) {
  while (str.length > 0 && remove.indexOf(str.charAt(0)) != -1) {
    str = str.substr(1);
  }
  while (str.length > 0 && remove.indexOf(str.charAt(str.length - 1)) != -1) {
    str = str.substr(0, str.length - 1);
  }
  return str;
}
```

A more effective, but not as easy to use, would be a regular expression:

```
str = str.replace(/(^[ '\^\$\*#&]+)|([ '\^\$\*#&]+$)/g, '')
```

Note: I escaped all characters that have any special meaning in a regular expression. You need to do that for some characters, but perhaps not all the ones that I escaped here as they are used inside a set. That's mostly to point out that some characters do need escaping.

Comment: Works for me as a makeshift solution.

Comment: Can you explain why the first method is not effective? Is this because its more lines of code, not as readable or not as efficient

Answer (score 19):

There's lodash's [`trim()`](https://lodash.com/docs#trim)

> Removes leading and trailing whitespace or specified characters from string.

```
_.trim('  abc  ');             // → 'abc'

_.trim('-_-abc-_-', '_-');     // → 'abc'
```

Answer (score 4):

Modifying a code snippet from [Mozilla Developer Network String.prototype.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim), you could define such a function as follows.

```
if (!String.prototype.strip) {
  String.prototype.strip = function (string) {
    var escaped = string.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
    return this.replace(RegExp("^[" + escaped + "]+|[" + escaped + "]+$", "gm"), '');
  };
}
```

It's not necessary and probably not advisable to put this function in the object `String.prototype`, but it does give you a clear indication of how such a function compares with the existing `String.prototype.trim()`.

The value of `escaped` is as in the function `escapeRegExp` in the [guide to Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). The Java programming language has a standard library function for that purpose, but [JavaScript does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593637/how-to-escape-regular-expression-in-javascript).

Comment: This is a great answer. But it's worth explaining the part the OP appears to have been missing—he knew how to use a regexp to strip `&` at the start and end, he just apparently didn't know how to use a character class to strip any of `[*#&]`. Your answer fixes that, but doesn't explain what it's doing differently from his attempt.

Comment: OK. Revised to take the chars to strip in a string parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly... I would use regex for complicated string manipulation or the Slice() method to remove characters at certain points
[Slice() explained](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp)